# What is the naming convention to name .net web user control?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, webusercontrol

I've always named my user controls XXXControl.ascx, but today I saw another experienced developer use "UCXXX.ascx"...I think the "UCXXX" approach is more consistent with naming Sprocs (UP_XXX, for example), but the "XXXControl" approach is more in line w/ VS's default behavior (in VS, when you create a new control, the name is "WebUserControl.ascx". What is the more conventional way?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily take stored-procedure naming conventions as a cue for how to name my GUI objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly depends on you and what you're comfortable with, unless the architect has decided otherwise and proposed some company standards. Both are good.

As for my personal touch, I prefer `XxxControl`, as I prefer to name a label `FirstNameLabel` instead of `lblFirstName`.

As for .NET, it sounds like the `XxxControl` is the prefered approach since VS names it this way. Here are some links I hope will guide you.

1. [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28vs.71%29.aspx);
2. [.net Naming Conventions and Programming Standards - Best Practices](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices);
3. [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) (choose whatever your .NET language is);
4. [Naming guidelines and code conventions](http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=namingconventions).

As for the stored procedure naming, you have to consider that database programming and object programming have quite nothing in common when it comes to standards. So I wouldn't rely on stored procedures and database objects to name my GUI objects.